# Samba access to all users with write permission to home directory only

Tags: samba, redhat

The system is RHEL 5.3.

We have several users with home directories /export/home/. All users belong to the same group devel.

How do I configure smb.conf so that each user can browse directories of all other users but have write permission to their home directory only?

Answer (score 1):

Think that might be more of an underlying file system permission question than a Samba one.  Assuming the Samba process allowing access runs as the authenticated user connecting to the share, then it follows that user would require the access.

Adding /export/home as a share, including devel group ownership and read permissions on all sub-directories should in theory solve your problem.  Of course, this doesn't address automatically adding the required settings on new user creation...